# Raphael JavaScript X undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael

quite the novice when it comes to Web etc. I'm using the Raphael.js Library to create a line chart, however I keep getting this error:

Unable to get property 'x' of undefined or null reference

And it highlights this piece of text within the Raphael.js File:

d=a.x

Am I missing something really simple ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Well, obviously `a` is undefined or null. Could you provide a little bit more code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mapael.js , check if you have exactly this code :

```
        <div class="mapClass">
            <div class="map">
                <span>Alternative content for the map</span>
            </div>
            <div class="areaLegend">
                <span>Alternative content for the legend</span>
            </div>
            <div class="plotLegend">
                <span>Alternative content for the legend</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Because .areaLegend  and .plotLegend are compulsory